# how do you create a folder and write to heroku's ephemeral storage?

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, google-cloud-storage

i'm using nodejs, and when my script uses fs.mkdir nothing seems to happen... it works well locally. is there an alternate command/function i can use to create and write to folders in heroku's file system?

(yes i'm aware the ephemeral system is temporary, with my use case, all files will be deleted after 5 minutes)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `tmp` folder in the root of your project, which is where you will write to and read files from in Heroku. For instance, first line of code below allows you to save data to a specified file path inside the `tmp` folder. The second line creates the stream for that file

```js
        fs.writeFileSync(`/tmp/${filename}.json`, dataToSave)
        const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(`/tmp/${filename}.json`)
```